# run mongo in docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker

i want to run mongoDb with docker in windows 10 for nodejs Project .

i run this command :

```
docker run --name CMSStore -p 27011:27017 -v e:/data/mongo:/data/db mongo
```

but it stop in this stop and not run .

[image: enter code here]

**whats the problem ? how can i run mongo with save data in valume ????**

Comment: If you do not have `mongo` image locally, it will take some time to pull from `docker.io`, also make sure you have an active internet connection.
If this is not the issue, then you seems to have permission issue with shell, try to run `power-shell` as administrator.

Comment: @SachithMuhandiram i check all of things . run adminsistrator and pull mongo but still have aproblem

Comment: can you run other `docker` commands, such as `docker -v`, does it give a response? I havent used docker in Windows. I just gave some basic tasks that you can debug your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
docker run -d -p 27017:27017 -v ~/data:/data/db mongo
```

Are you sure that 27011 is listening ? why you using it? 
Default port are here :
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/default-mongodb-port/
27017, 27018, 27019.

To see if mongodb is listening on 27011, check this command on mongo shell:

```
db.runCommand({whatsmyuri : 1})
```

it will display IP and port numbers in use.